# displayOrder not found on object of type 'NSManagedObject'

Tags: ios

For some weird reason, I am having difficulties trying to access .displayOrder from a CoreData object. When I NSLog the object out, all the info including order data shows up, so I am pretty sure the data exists on the object.

```
NSManagedObject *curObj = [_aFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];

curObj.displayOrder (This is where I get error message - "displayOrder not found....")
```

Also, .displayOrder shows up when I do something like self.curObj.displayOrder, but of course does not work like this.

Hope someone can shed some light on this and thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the whole crash log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than assigning a generic NSManagedObject the object from your tableView, you should probably be using your custom NSManagedObject. Eg -

```
MyCustomObject *curObj = [_aFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:fromIndexPath];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup that was it and now makes sense it couldn't find the data. Thanks again! :)